# http/1.1 404 not found and arabic file name delphi

Tags: delphi, http, post, http-post, delphi-xe7

I have two problem :

1- my application can't upload any file 'txt or doc' that have Arabic name !

2- my project didn't upload image , and show this exception:

**http/1.1 404 not found delphi**

**Note: my application upload only english text file**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  StreamFiles: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
  path : string;
begin
  StreamFiles := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  path :=  'D:\image.jpg' ;
  try
    StreamFiles.AddFile('upload_file', path, 'image/jpeg');
    try
    IdHTTP1.Post('http://myserver.com/upload/image', StreamFiles);
    except
     on E: Exception do
       ShowMessage('Error encountered during POST: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    StreamFiles.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: 404 Not found is there for a reason - the page was not found. You use an incorrect URL. You should be able to upload any file with any filename if you use correct encoding - UTF-8. See http://forums2.atozed.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=25804 (Set HeaderCharset and HeaderEncoding). Your question is not complete to find out..

Comment: Agreed.  An HTTP 404 response has nothing to do with the filenames that are being posted, but rather with the URL that is being posted to. It means `/upload/image` does not exist on `myserver.com`

Comment: smooty & remyLebeau thank u , it's work.